# Python-TCP SYN scan without using driver

Tags: python, scapy, nmap, port-scanning

Is it possible to write TCP SYN scan (half-open scanning) in python without using driver? I want to implement this kind of scanning in python without using scapy as I know it requires installing a driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, BSD, OSX, yeah sure, using Raw sockets.

I assume if you talk about a "driver" it means you're on Windows in which case you will be restricted (can't access layer 2), and will require administrative privileges anyways.

In any case, you can still use Scapy without any "driver" (libpcap-based) installed. Some functions will be disabled